# Jquery paralax effect functions

Tags: jquery

Basically, what I'm asking for is opinions on the best way to do the following;

I basically have this already: http://jsfiddle.net/BnJ3G/1/ which is more or less a background animation depending on the scroll event. Similar to a paralax type function.

I just wanted to know, the easiest way to tackle multiple axis with little coding, I have around 10 different things I need to apply this effect to, but at the moment I'm limited to the +x axis, where as I need (+X, -X, +Y and -Y). Is there someway this can be altered so that I can do something simple like this outside of the main function?

```
$('#element1').animatePosX(percentage);
$('#element2').animateNegY(percentage);
```

Etc...

I'd love the help if possible!

Answer (score 0):

We develop a jQuery plugin to do this of a easy way: http://globocom.github.com/destaque/
It's not so simple to achieve this effects just with animate.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure out the basic math to simply simulate a parallax scroll. This might not be the finest way to add parallax to a site, but it's currently functioning for me. Hopefully it will be a helpful starting point for someone else. It doesn't affect size or blur or anything -- only the speed of scrolling.

```js
// i is id, t is distance from top, d is depth (1-100)
// depth of 50 will scroll at normal scroll speed.
plax = [{
    "i": "sue",
    "t": 50,
    "d": 90
  },
  {
    "i": "mark",
    "t": 100,
    "d": 50
  },
  {
    "i": "janis",
    "t": 500,
    "d": 50
  },
  {
    "i": "donna",
    "t": 300,
    "d": 1
  }
];


$window = $(window);
$(function() {
  $.each(plax, function() {
    eyedee = "#" + this['i'];
    $(eyedee).addClass("plax");
    m = mathIt(this['d'], this['t']);
    $(eyedee).css({
      "top": m,
      "z-index": -this['d']
    });

  });
  $window.scroll(function() {
    $.each(plax, function() {
      eyedee = "#" + this['i'];
      m = mathIt(this['d'], this['t']);

      $(eyedee).css("top", m);
    });
  });
});

function mathIt(d, t) {
  return ((((d - 50) * 2) / 100) * $(window).scrollTop()) + t;
}
```

```css
.plax {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sue">here's sue</div>
<div id="mark">
  <h2>here's mark</h2>
</div>
<div id="donna">
  <h1>here's donna</h1>
</div>
<div id="janis">
  <h2>here's janis</h2>
</div>
```